How can I report a VARX model (MTS class) with modelsummary (or other LaTeX table packages) in R?
Consider an example of a VARX model estimate in R, using MTS package:
library(tidyverse)
library(MTS)
library(modelsummary)
library(vars)
library(stats)

set.seed(10)

ts1 <- rnorm(200, mean = 10, sd = 3) %>% ts()
ts2 <- ts1 + rnorm(200, mean = 1, sd = 3) %>% ts()

exg1 <- rchisq(n = 200,df = 10) + ts1 %>% ts()
exg2 <- rf(n = 200,df1 = 20,df2 = 20) + ts2 %>% ts()

zt <- cbind(ts1, ts2)
xt <- cbind(exg1, exg2)
p = 1
m = 0

varx <- VARX(zt = zt, p = p, xt = xt, m = m)

I would like to report this model as a LaTeX table, such as the output table of a lm() model:
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{lc}
\toprule
  & ts1\\
\midrule
(Intercept) & \num{1.676}\\
 & (\num{0.640})\\
ts2\_lag & \num{0.133}\\
 & \vphantom{1} (\num{0.223})\\
exg1 & \num{0.165}\\
 & (\num{0.028})\\
exg2 & \num{0.273}\\
 & (\num{0.223})\\
\midrule
Num.Obs. & \num{200}\\
R2 & \num{0.561}\\
R2 Adj. & \num{0.554}\\
AIC & \num{832.4}\\
BIC & \num{848.9}\\
Log.Lik. & \num{-411.211}\\
F & \num{83.346}\\
RMSE & \num{1.89}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

According to modelsummary, I can report this model if I create a tidy.mts function that returns a dataframe with a column called term and a glance.mts function with goodness of fit statistics.
But the following code doesn't produce a modelsummary table:

tidy.mts <- function(s, ...) {
  
  colnames(s$se.coef) <- colnames(s$coef)
  
  ret <- data.frame(
    term= rownames(s$coef),
    estimate= round(s$coef,3),
    std.error= round(s$se.coef,3))
  
  ret
}

glance.mts <- function(s, ...) {
  
  ret <- data.frame(
    n = nrow(s$data)
  )
  ret
}

modelsummary(varx)

The error message is:
Error: `modelsummary could not extract the required information from a model of
  class "mts". The package tried a sequence of 2 helper functions to extract
  estimates:
  
  parameters::parameters(model)
  broom::tidy(model)
  
  To draw a table, one of these commands must return a `data.frame` with a
  column named "term". The `modelsummary` website explains how to summarize
  unsupported models or add support for new models yourself:
  https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html
  
  These errors messages were generated during extraction:
  
  `parameters::parameters(model)` did not return a valid data.frame.
`broom::tidy(model)` did not return a valid data.frame.
In addition: Warning message:
`modelsummary could not extract goodness-of-fit statistics from a model
of class "mts". The package tried a sequence of 2 helper functions:

performance::model_performance(model)
broom::glance(model)

One of these functions must return a one-row `data.frame`. The `modelsummary` website explains how to summarize unsupported models or add support for new models yourself:

https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html 


There are many problems in your solution.

The varx object is of class list, not of class mts, which is what your tidy and glance methods look for. You can manually assign your model a class: class(varx)<-"mts"
The estimate and std.error columns in tidy() should not be rounded. They should be numeric values.
estimate and std.error columns in tidy() should be a single column. However, when you call s$coef, you get two columns. Make sure calling tidy(varx) produces the same kind of data frame as when you call the same function on a lm() model.
The number of observations should be called nobs. This will ensure that it is nicely renamed in the table.


This is very helpful!
I was able to fix problems 1., 2. and 4. in a satisfactory manner. For problem 3. changing the code to the folowing produces an output with the first column of s$coef and s$se.coef.
`
tidy.mts <- function(s, ...) {
colnames(s$se.coef) <- colnames(s$coef)
ret <- data.frame(
term= rownames(s$coef),
estimate= s$coef[,1],
std.error= s$se.coef[,1]
)
ret
}
`
I wonder if it's possible to make the table have two columns of estimate and std.error (one for each equation). I tried the following code but received an error message.

  
  colnames(s$se.coef) <- colnames(s$coef)
  
  ret <- data.frame(
    term= rownames(s$coef),
    estimate_1= s$coef[,1],
    std.error_1= s$se.coef[,1],
    estimate_2= s$coef[,2],
    std.error_2= s$se.coef[,2]
    )
  
  ret
}```

You can put the coefficients one after the other, create a column called group. Your tidy(model) data frame will have twice as many rows, with the group column distinguishing the sets of coefs. Then use the shape argument to structure the table any way you want. This is similar to a categorical outcome model, where there are coefficients for different levels of the outcome. There are examples of that on the website.

It worked! Thank you very much.
The only problem was that Goodness of Fit statistics were not included in the table after using shape .
But this seems to have been handled in another question.
I will post my final code as an answer in case it's helpful for others.

The following code fixes almost every problem I found, except for the lack of goodness of fit in the table after using the shape command. This problem was already handled in another question.I thank Vincent for his help!
Note that this code is not generalized to more than two endogenous variables in vector zt.
library(MTS)
library(modelsummary)
library(vars)
library(stats)

set.seed(10)

ts1 <- rnorm(200, mean = 10, sd = 3) %>% ts()
ts2 <- ts1 + rnorm(200, mean = 1, sd = 3) %>% ts()

exg1 <- rchisq(n = 200,df = 10) + ts1 %>% ts()
exg2 <- rf(n = 200,df1 = 20,df2 = 20) + ts2 %>% ts()

zt <- cbind(ts1, ts2)
xt <- cbind(exg1, exg2)
p = 1
m = 0

varx <- VARX(zt = zt, p = p, xt = xt, m = m)

class(varx) <- "mts"

tidy.mts <- function(s, ...) {
  
  colnames(s$se.coef) <- colnames(s$coef)
  
  ret <- data.frame(
    term= rownames(s$coef),
    estimate= c(
                s$coef[,1],
                s$coef[,2]
                ),
    std.error= c(
                 s$se.coef[,1],
                 s$se.coef[,2]
                 ),
    group=c(
            rep(colnames(s$coef)[1],times = nrow(s$coef)),
            rep(colnames(s$coef)[2],times = nrow(s$coef))
            )
    )
  
  ret
}

glance.mts <- function(s, ...) {
  
  ret <- data.frame(
    nobs = nrow(s$data)
  )
  ret
}

modelsummary(varx,shape = term + statistic ~ group)```

